# How to hide grub2 menu?

Tags: boot, grub2, uninstall

I need some help, I screwed up while trying to auto-mount on boot my USB external HDD, something went wrong and it doesn't boot to Ubuntu.

I installed this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and I ran it to repair the boot, and now I have a boot menu.

The menu shows down booting and I don't need it so how do I remove it?

Comment: I think you do need GRUB, it is the program that *boots* your computer. You could install an alternate bootloader if you needed to, though

Comment: tks @minerz029 thing is, i did a fresh install on an empty hdd, and on first boot and the next ones util i screw up grub was never showed. maybe i can disable it ?

Comment: GRUB never *showed* because usually, you press Shift when booting to show GRUB, otherwise it is hidden. Boot repair shows GRUB for you

Comment: by "you press shift" you mean that i have deslocated my hand and finger near shift button and pressing it ?

It didn't never happen, not on boot.

Comment: I think the most helpful resource on this would be the configuration documentation which is *not* the first thing you'll find when using a search engine: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Simple-configuration.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the following steps to **hide** GRUB (it is still installed)

1. Run this command in terminal

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Set these lines (create them if they don't exist), doesn't have to be this order

   ```
   GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
   GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
   GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
   GRUB_DEFAULT=0
   ```
3. Save then close the file
4. Run this command in terminal

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

actually I was having this menu already configured...

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I did it by removing word ***splash*** from second last line :)

cool right?

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. I got the grub menu for 10 seconds.